# Specify collection in WPF Property setter

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a Dependency Property for items on a legend.  It looks like:

```
    public List<LegendItem> LegendItems
    {
        get { return (List<LegendItem>)GetValue(LegendItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LegendItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LegendItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LegendItems", typeof(List<LegendItem>), typeof(TipScoreboard), new PropertyMetadata());
```

where `LegendItem` is a `UserControl`.

I am able to set it in XAML like this with no problem.

```
<local:TipScoreboard.LegendItems>
    <local:LegendItem ItemFillBrush="{DynamicResource GreenStatusBrush}"
                      Label="{x:Static res:TipLabels.GoodScan}"/>
    <local:LegendItem ItemFillBrush="{DynamicResource RedStatusBrush}"
                      Label="{x:Static res:TipLabels.BadScan}"/>
</local:TipScoreboard.LegendItems>
```

However when I go to set this property in a setter like this:

```
<Setter Property="LegendItems">
     <Setter.Value>
         <local:LegendItem ItemFillBrush="{DynamicResource GreenStatusBrush}"
                           Label="{x:Static res:TipLabels.GoodScan}"/>
         <local:LegendItem ItemFillBrush="{DynamicResource YellowStatusBrush}"
                           Label="{x:Static res:TipLabels.LowConfidence}"/>
      </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
```

I get the `The property "Value" is set more than once.` for the setter.  I'm not sure how to wrap this or what to do.  I've tried just wrapping a List around it but that didn't seem to work.

**EDIT**: I tried created a custom wrapped collection and everything complies and run but the content is blank.

```
public class LegendItemCollection : Collection<LegendItem>
{
}

public LegendItemCollection LegendItems
{
    get { return (LegendItemCollection)GetValue(LegendItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LegendItemsProperty, value); }
}

 public static readonly DependencyProperty LegendItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LegendItems", typeof(LegendItemCollection), typeof(TipScoreboard), new PropertyMetadata());
```

and the XAML:

```
<Setter Property="LegendItems">
    <Setter.Value>
       <local:LegendItemCollection>
           <local:LegendItem ItemFillBrush="{DynamicResource GreenStatusBrush}"
                             Label="{x:Static res:TipLabels.GoodScan}"/>
           <local:LegendItem ItemFillBrush="{DynamicResource YellowStatusBrush}"
                             Label="{x:Static res:TipLabels.LowConfidence}"/>
       </local:LegendItemCollection>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 6):

One way to handle this is to change the dependency property's type to a class that wraps `List<LegendItem>`:

```
public class LegendItemCollection : List<LegendItem>
{
}

public LegendItemCollection LegendItems
{
    get { return (LegendItemCollection)GetValue(LegendItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LegendItemsProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty LegendItemsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("LegendItems", typeof(LegendItemCollection), typeof(TipScoreboard), 
        new PropertyMetadata((sender, args) => {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("LegendItems property set");
        }));
```

Then you can set the property straightforwardly in XAML:

```
<Setter Property="LegendItems">
     <Setter.Value>
         <local:LegendItemCollection>
             <local:LegendItem ItemFillBrush="{DynamicResource GreenStatusBrush}"
                               Label="{x:Static res:TipLabels.GoodScan}"/>
             <local:LegendItem ItemFillBrush="{DynamicResource YellowStatusBrush}"
                               Label="{x:Static res:TipLabels.LowConfidence}"/>
         </local:LegendItemCollection>
      </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
```

---

I believe that, in theory, you can achieve the same thing without needing the wrapper collection class, declaring a `List<T>` in XAML by using [x:TypeArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750476%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  I can't seem to get this to work, though ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6053379/1001985)).  According to the docs the declaration would look something like this:

```
<Setter Property="LegendItems">
     <Setter.Value>
         <scg:List xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib"
                   x:TypeArguments="local:LegendItem">
             <local:LegendItem ItemFillBrush="{DynamicResource GreenStatusBrush}"
                               Label="{x:Static res:TipLabels.GoodScan}"/>
             <local:LegendItem ItemFillBrush="{DynamicResource YellowStatusBrush}"
                               Label="{x:Static res:TipLabels.LowConfidence}"/>
         </scg:List>
      </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
```

However, the above code gives me a compiler error:

> The name 'List' does not exist in the namespace 'clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib'

---

**Edit**

Per the comments, the solution to the edit in the OP is to use [`SetCurrentValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx) instead of assigning a property directly (the latter wipes out any styling on the property due to [dependency property value precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
this.SetCurrentValue(LegendItemsProperty, new LegendItemCollection());
```

Comment: I tried the custom wrapper and it ran but didn't seem to work.  Just shows up blank.  I got the same error as you when trying the List<T> approach.

Comment: @BrianTriplett are you sure you updated the DP type to "LegendItemCollection" in all 3 spots?  That's the only thing I can think of right now.  You could also check for binding errors in the output window...

Comment: I did check and they are all set correctly. What about the initialization?  In the constructor for the view I have `this.LegendItems = new LegendItemCollection();
InitializeComponent();`

Comment: @BrianTriplett why would you instantiate LegendItems in the view?  For your code snippet `<Setter Property="LegendItems">`, I got the impression that you wanted to set LegendItems using a style (or is it a trigger?)

Comment: I need to set it in a style because there are triggers that change the items.

Comment: @BrianTriplett gotcha ... so, my concern is that, if you write `this.LegendItems = new LegendItemCollection()`, this sets a local value for the property.  Therefore, any style on that property will not be applied, because the local value takes precedence.

Comment: That was it!  It worked if I set it directly in XAML but as soon as I put it in a style it did not work.  It was because of value precedence.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231478/binding-setting-property-but-ui-not-updating-can-i-debug-within-referenced-proj for the solution with `SetCurrentValue`.  If you want to add that you your answer I'll accept since you've been very helpful.

Comment: @BrianTriplett interesting, I didn't know about SetCurrentValue.  I edited your note into my answer.